# pylint invalid name error (C0103) doesn't follow python conventions

Tags: python, lint, pylint, pep

I have a private variable in a class - `_expected_substring_result` . 
This is the line 26 in my module, which is part of my init function - `self._expected_substring_result = _expected_substring_result`.

This is the error I'm getting from lint-python -
`..\endpoint.py:26:4: C0103: Attribute name "_expected_substring_result" doesn't conform to '[a-z_][a-z0-9_]{0,30}$' pattern (invalid-name)` .

This  doesn't make sense -  a private field in python is supposed to begin with an underscore. 
I know how to fix it, by either editing the linter config, or adding `# pylint: disable=invalid-name`. But this seems too odd an issue to just be something the pylint devs forgot about.

Is this a  bug, or am I missing something ?
Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give to pylint the format you use for attribute names with the `--attr-rgx` option.  For example to have attribute starting with possibly two underscores:

```
pylint --attr-rgx=_?_?[a-z0-9]+(_[a-z]+)*_?_?$ ...
```

Several such naming schemes can be defined: for class names, for module names, ...

You can also edit your `pylintrc` file to change this parameter.

Comment: That was a valid regex, cool!

Answer (score 1):

pylint 3.0.0-a4 doesn't find your error in this code snippet below.
Please provide your `__init__` for further investigation :)

```
class Hi:
    def __init__(self, _expected_substring_result):
        self._expected_substring_result = _expected_substring_result
```